# Building projects targeting .NET Compact Framework

Tags: .net, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I'm working with someone that is trying to get source code building for a very old app targeting Windows Mobile 6 and the .NET Compact Framework on .NET 3.5. I'm trying to figure out exactly what my options are to try and move this across the line. I *think* Visual Studio 2008 is the last supported version for this, so I assume I'd need to get a full-blown MSDN license to get that version and try to get a build going. I'm not certain though, and the documentation around all of this from almost 15 years ago is not great.

Has anyone had to set up a from-scratch environment for something like this recently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed and run VS 2008 Prof. on different OS, like Windows XP, Windows 7 and Windows 10. The older ones (Win7 and WinXP) in virtual machines.

You may buy 'used Software Visual Studio 2008', for example at amazon or other sources. OTOH a Developer Net Account is needed to download and run this old version. Furtunately I have a MSDN account and able to download this old VS2008 and then Windows XP or so to install everything in a virtual machine or on a separate PC.

Further on, you need the free Windows Mobile 6 SDK to get the runtimes and libs for the device and the build system. The .Net CF runtimes are mostly part of the device's OS image.

I could help with changing the code and build the software, but do not have any device left with Mobile 6 to test the code.

Comment: This is essentially what I had to do. Spin up a VM running Windows Datacenter 2012 in Azure (newer had trouble opening the VS2008 iso), installing VS2008, installing Windows Mobile 6 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

Important is that you buy Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition. Standard Edition won't be able to build and run compact framework projects. Vs2008 is still running in Windows 10. So no need to change the operating system.